# recognize the sequence numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, soft-question, math-software

Is there software that can recognize the logical link between sequence numbers?

**Example 1:**
$$\begin{array}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|c}
\hline
\text{sequence} & 2 & 6 & 12 & 20 & 30  & \cdots \\
\hline
n & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & \cdots \\
\hline
\end{array}$$
Here the $n$th term of the sequence is $n(n+1)$.

**Example 2:**

$$\begin{array}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
\hline
\text{sequence} & 2 & 8 & 24 & 64 & 160 & 384 & \cdots \\
\hline
n & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & \cdots \\
\hline
\end{array}$$
Here the $n$th term of the sequence is $n 2^n$.

Thank you.

Comment: http://oeis.org/

Comment: For typing text in Latex do \text{....} between two $'s, Amir.

Comment: @Babak Sorouh ،Thank you.

Comment: @Amir: I have quite substantially re-formatted the question.  If you like it, good.  If not, feel free to either revert or improve.

Comment: @ArthurFischer, the original form was good to copy and paste into Wolfram Alpha, which I did.

Comment: @Arthur Fischer: Thank you so much.I like it.
I'm beginner and my english language is very weak 
so I Appreciate for correction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[OEIS](http://oeis.org/) is excellent, the database is huge. If you don't have web access, you can also send an email.
Results by an offline software are much more limited, but Mathematica has the [FindSequenceFunction[]](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html) function. However, it doesn't seem to find your second example...

Comment: OEIS is very helpful , thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

[Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) solves the first sequence with

> http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%2C6%2C12%2C20%2C30%2C...

and the second sequence with

> http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%2C8%2C24%2C64%2C160%2C384%2C...

Answer (score 1):

Your Second Sequence has error with 264 instead of 384.

OEIS is the best I know of:

http://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C8%2C24%2C64%2C160&sort=&language=english&go=Search

is very helpful to search sequences.

There might not be such offline softwares.

At least I don't know one.

Comment: Thank you for correct the error.