# Calculate affiliaton of items from disjoint sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a couple of disjoint sequences and want to calculate to which sequence an item belongs to. The formation of the sequences is well known: The sequences $m$ form by incrementing a number $n$ in various intervals $i_k$ based on a stepsize $\sigma$ one after another.

An example: We have sequence $a$ with an interval $i_a=1$ and $b$ with an interval $i_b=i_a=1$. The sequences are formed like this:

$
\begin{array}{c|ccccccccc}
\sigma & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5  & \ldots \\\hline
a & 0 & 2 & 4 & 6 & 8 & 10 & \ldots \\
b & 1 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 9 & 11 & \ldots \\
\end{array}
$

For this simple example the sequences are $a=(0,2,4,6,8,10,\ldots)$ and $b=(1,3,5,7,9,11,\ldots)$ and the affiliation is easily calculated, since $a$ has only even and $b$ only odd numbers:

$
m(n) = \begin{cases}
a & \text{if }n \bmod 2 = 0\\
b & \text{if }n \bmod 2 = 1\\
\end{cases}
$

But how can I formulate an equation, if there are 3 sequences with the same interval? Then there is no trivial odd-even pattern, but alternating ones:

$
\begin{array}{c|ccccccccc}
\sigma & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5  & \ldots \\\hline
a & 0 & 3 & 6 & 9  & 12 & 15 & \ldots \\
b & 1 & 4 & 7 & 10 & 13 & 16 & \ldots \\
c & 2 & 5 & 8 & 11 & 14 & 17 & \ldots \\
\end{array}
$

What to do with sequences with different intervals? For example $i_a=1$ and $i_b=2$. Or $i_a=2$ and $i_b=1$?

$
\begin{array}{c|ccccccccc}
\sigma & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5  & \ldots \\\hline
a_{i=1} & 0 & 2 & 3 & 5 & 6 & 8 & \ldots \\
b_{i=2} & 1 &   & 4 &   & 7 &   & \ldots \\
\end{array}
\qquad
\begin{array}{c|ccccccccc}
\sigma & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5  & \ldots \\\hline
a_{i=2} & 0 &   & 3 &   & 6 &   & \ldots \\
b_{i=1} & 1 & 2 & 4 & 5 & 7 & 8 & \ldots \\
\end{array}
$

In these examples the sequence with the higher interval $i_k$ ($b$) is more obvious (to me) and $a$ can be defined by the opposite:

$m_{i_a=1, i_b=2}(n)=\begin{cases}
a & \text{if } (n+1)\bmod 3 \not= 0\\
b & \text{if } (n+1)\bmod 3 = 0
\end{cases}$

But what if there are even more sequences $a,b,\ldots,h$ and various random but fixed intervals $1,7,42,1000,\ldots$?

Does anyone know an approach to my problem?

Is there a solution where I can define the formulas programmatically based on the given $m$s and $i$s?

**Edit:** I have found this question: [recognize the sequence numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265233/recognize-the-sequence-numbers) where the website http://oeis.org/ is mentioned. With it I found the (in retrospect easy) answer for the 2nd example:

$m_{i_a=1, i_b=1, i_c=1}(n)=\begin{cases}
a & \text{if } (3n)\bmod 3 = 0\\
b & \text{if } (3n+1)\bmod 3 = 0\\
b & \text{if } (3n+2)\bmod 3 = 0
\end{cases}$

But the other sequences don't seem to be so easy…